# In angular, how do I access a class method from component.ts?

Tags: angular, class, highcharts

I am working on an angular project where I have a button where I want it to hide all but a particular series on a highchart. This is probably something simple, but I have only been doing web development for a little while and I'm a bit lacking on some of the basics. Im not really a web developer but agreed to take on some of the work instead of having the company hire someone who knew what they were doing. Anyway, a proper developer setup the project for me and showed me how to do what I wanted to do but he is currently on leave and I've become a little stuck.

So, I am using highcharts to display some data. I have a highcharts folder with a reusable component called highcharts-component.ts that looks like this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { chart } from "highcharts";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import drilldown from "highcharts/modules/drilldown.src.js";
drilldown(Highcharts);
declare var require: any;
require("highcharts/highcharts-more")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/solid-gauge")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/heatmap")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/treemap")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/funnel")(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  styleUrls: ["./styles.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./template.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @Input()
  set options(value: Highcharts.Options) {
    this._options = value;
    this.chart = chart(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this._options);
  }

  private chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;
  private _options: Highcharts.Options;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chart = null;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = chart(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this._options);
  }

  public showSingleSeries(seriesNumber) {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.chart.series.length; x++) {
      if (x == seriesNumber) {
        this.chart.series[seriesNumber].show();
      } else {
        this.chart.series[seriesNumber].hide();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my component file called card-fancy-example.ts I have something like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

/**
 * @title Card with multiple sections
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'card-fancy-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-fancy-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-fancy-example.css'],
})
export class CardFancyExample {

   myChart: Highcharts.Options = {
    // Created pie chart using Highchart
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Contents using Pie chart'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          innerSize: 100,
          depth: 45
        }
      }
  };
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadChart();  
  }

  loadChart()
  {
    this.myChart = {
      ...this.myChart,
       series: [{
        name: 'Operating Systems',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Windows',
            y: 88.19,
            drilldown: 'windows-versions'
          },
          ['MacOSX', 9.22],
          ['Linux', 1.58],
          ['Others', 1.01]
        ]
      }],
      drilldown: {
        series: [{
          name: 'Windows versions',
          id: 'windows-versions',
          data: [
            ['Win 7', 55.03],
            ['Win XP', 15.83],
            ['Win Vista', 3.59],
            ['Win 8', 7.56],
            ['Win 8.1', 6.18]
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  showSingleSeries(seriesNumber)
  { 
    // Where I want to call the showSingleSeries method in highcharts-component.ts
  }

}
```

and my html file looks like this:

```
 <button (click)="showSingleSeries(0)">Remove All Series But Windows</button>
<button (click)="showSingleSeries(1)">Remove All Series But Linux</button>

    <app-chart [options]="myChart"></app-chart>
```

The chart loads correctly but now when I click on a particular button I want to be able to only show either the "Windows" or the "MacOSX" series. I have a method to do this in highcharts-component.ts called showSingleSeries which looks like this:

```
public showSingleSeries(seriesNumber) {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.chart.series.length; x++) {
      if (x == seriesNumber) {
        this.chart.series[x].show();
      } else {
        this.chart.series[x].hide();
      }
    }
  }
```

The thing is, I don't know enough about angular to know how I can access this showSingleSeries method? How do I do this? Here is what I have in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mt9v8j)

Thanks.

EDIT: I edited a couple of bugs in my code and changed the chart type. I have updated stackblitz with the solution. Thanks @Lys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

you want the parent to call the childs method. you should use view child.

in the html 
`<app-chart [options]="myChart" #charts></app-chart>`

in the ts file
`@ViewChild('charts') charts;`
then call it `this.charts.showSingleSeries(1);`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I have a follow-up question. If I was to move the method to a new file, the ``this.chart`` object wouldn't be in the file, right?